# Date substraction why don't I get hh:mm:ss in Rebol / Red?

Tags: rebol, red

1°) I get only the number of days, how to also get the hh:mm:ss ?

```
diff: (now - (10-Nov-2017/15:00:00))
```

> 6

2°) What's the most elegant way to get the number of minutes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1°) I get only the number of days, how to also get the hh:mm:ss ?

Use `difference` function for that:

```
>> difference now 10-Nov-2017/15:00:00
== 145:19:24
```

> 2°) What's the most elegant way to get the number of minutes ?

The same way as for any other date value:

```
>> d: difference now 10-Nov-2017/15:00:00
>> d/minute
== 21
```

Alternatively, you can use `pick` to avoid setting the intermediary date to a word:

```
>> pick (difference now 10-Nov-2017/15:00:00) 2  ; Red and Rebol2/3
== 21
>> pick (difference now 10-Nov-2017/15:00:00) 'minute ; Rebol3, not yet implemented in Red
== 21
```